# How to store multiple datatypes in an array?

Tags: java, android, arrays, google-maps

I'm looking for something like an Array, but it needs to store multiple data types. The Oracle Java tutorials says, "An array is a container object that holds a fixed number of values of a single type." So if I can't use an array for multiple types, what do I use?

I've got this code that only adds one marker to the map at a time because it writes over my lat and long values each loop and only passes the last to the onPostExecute. So I will need something like an array to pass multiple forms of contact info. ie I'm pulling the location from each JSON string, but I need to pull and pass the name & phone number too to the UI from this background thread.

```
try {

    String apples = endpoint.listContactInfo().execute().toString();

    JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(apples);

    JSONArray jsonArr = jObject.getJSONArray("items");

     for(int i =0 ; i<jsonArr.length() ;i++ ){
         JSONObject jsonObj1 = jsonArr.getJSONObject(i);


                    // Storing each json item in variable
                    String id = jsonObj1.getString(TAG_ID);
                    String nameFirst1 = jsonObj1.getString(TAG_FIRSTNAME);
                    String nameLast1 = jsonObj1.getString(TAG_LASTNAME);
                    String emailAddress1 = jsonObj1.getString(TAG_EMAIL);
                    String streetAddress1 = jsonObj1.getString(TAG_ADDRESS);
                    String phone1 = jsonObj1.getString(TAG_PHONE);

                    //test to see if made it to string
                    Log.d("YOUR_TAG", "First Name: " + nameFirst1 + " Last Name: " + nameLast1);

                       address = coder.getFromLocationName(streetAddress1,5);

                        Address location1 = address.get(0);

                        // SET LAT LNG VALUES FOR MARKER POINT

                     lati = location1.getLatitude();
                         longi = location1.getLongitude();



                         Log.d("Location", "Location:" + lati + " " +  longi);


     }

    } catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  } catch (JSONException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
      return (long) 0;


    }
         // ADD MARKER TO MAP UI
    protected void onPostExecute(Long result) {
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
        .position(new LatLng(lati, longi))
         .title("Hello world"));
    }
```

Comment: Does it have to be an array ? and cant you use arrayList? if so Phillip Johada's answer will work, if its not really necessary then you can use ArrayList<Object>  and sometimes type casting is necessary

Comment: Generally speaking, when you find yourself wanting to store multiple different types of data, you should be writing a new class to hold that type, rather than dumping all those objects into the same array or same list.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can create an **array of your Custom-Class.**

```
public class YourCustomClass {

     String id;
     String name;
     double longitude;
     // and many more fields ...

    public YourCustomClass() {  // constructor 

    }

    public void setID(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getID() {
        return id;
    }

    // and many more getter and setter methods ...
}
```

Inside your custom-class you can have as many fields as you want where you can store your data, and then use it like that:

```
// with array 
YourCustomClass [] array = new YourCustomClass[10];
array[0] = new YourCustomClass();
array[0].setID("yourid");

String id = array[0].getID();

// with arraylist
ArrayList<YourCustomClass> arraylist = new ArrayList<YourCustomClass>();
arraylist.add(new YourCustomObject());
arraylist.get(0).setID("yourid");

String id = arraylist.get(0).getID();
```

You can also let the AsyncTasks doInBackground(...) method return your Custom-class:

```
protected void onPostExecute(YourCustomClass result) {
 // do stuff...
}
```

Or an array:

```
protected void onPostExecute(YourCustomClass [] result) {
 // do stuff...
}
```

Or a ArrayList:

```
protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<YourCustomClass> result) {
 // do stuff...
}
```

**Edit:** Of course, you can also make a **ArrayList** of your custom object.

Answer (score 11):

You can use an `ArrayList`.

```
ArrayList<Object> listOfObjects = new ArrayList<Object>();
```

And then add items to it.

```
listOfObjects.add("1");
listOfObjects.add(someObject);
```

Or create your own object that encapsulates all the field that you require like

```
public class LocationData {
   private double lat;
   private double longitude;

   public LocationData(double lat, double longitude) {
       this.lat = lat;
       this.longitude = longitude;
   }
   //getters
   //setters
}
```

and then add your lat/long pairs to an `ArrayList` of type `LocationData`

```
ArrayList<LocationData> listOfObjects = new ArrayList<LocationData>();

listOfObjects.add(new LocationData(lat, longitude));
```

Comment: He can also do this with a regular array of `Object[]`

Comment: It would not recommend working on a raw `Object` array directly. It should be encapsulated behind some kind of safety mechanism.

Answer (score 6):

You should consider the use of the **[typesafe heterogeneous container pattern](http://books.google.de/books?id=ka2VUBqHiWkC&lpg=PA142&ots=yYJnLhu_U1&dq=typesafe%20heterogeneous%20container%20pattern&hl=de&pg=PA142#v=onepage&q=typesafe%20heterogeneous%20container%20pattern&f=false)**.

There the data is stored in a `Map<Key<?>, Object>` and access to the map is hidden behind generic methods, that automatically cast the return value.

```
public <T> T getObjectByKey(Key<T> key)
  return (T) map.get(key);
```

The same for `put`.

Answer (score 1):

The most simplistic way of storing objects of different data types is just by declaring the type of your Array(or Collection) as an "Object".

`Object[] arr = new Object[10];`

```
   arr[0] = "ab";
   arr[1] = 2;
   arr[2] = 2.3;
```

Java.lang.Object class is the root or superclass of the class hierarchy. All predefined classes and user-defined classes are the subclasses from the Object class. So, objects of all other classes are also of type "Object" and hence can be stored.