# How to store a collection of multiple datatypes in a vector in java?

Tags: java

I am from c++ background and in c++ we can use pointers and store a collection of multiple datatypes in a vector but how do we do this in java. 
For instance I want to store:
{name, price/pound, weight}
{name, price} 
It is a kind of a bakery receipt program.

Comment: BakeryItem seems to need to be only one class... So you make that an object that the Vector (preferably an Arraylist) would store

Comment: This is too general to provide a useful answer. Should us what your classes look like, what you're trying to do, and what you're stuck on.

Comment: @shmosel This is not too general for a C++ programmer. We are used to sticking all kinds of things all kinds of places, some of them not totally appropriate. Pointers can be beautiful and useful things.

Comment: See [How to store multiple datatypes in an array?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18624885/how-to-store-multiple-datatypes-in-an-array) which has solutions for a similar question.

Answer (score 3):

Java is a very Object Oriented type of language that leans heavily on classes and objects. You might find it easier to have a class for a `Receipt`, and then just store an array receipts

You may or may not want to have a list of `Products` in the `Receipt` class however. This way you can have multiple items on a single receipt. This would need a `Product` class as well though, and in the `Receipt` class, you could change `name`, `pricePerPound`, `weight` to a list of products, and your `Product` class would store those variables instead. Every Product would then have a name, price per pound, and a weight

```
public class Receipt {
    String name;
    double pricePerPound;
    double weight;

    //Constructor
    public Receipt() {

    }

    //Other methods can go here, like getters and setters
}
```

Then you can just have an array of `Receipts`

```
Receipt[] receipts = new Receipt[10];
```

Or you can use `java.util.ArrayList` to get a datatype which will vary in size

```
ArrayList<Receipt> receipts = new ArrayList<>(); //ArrayList of type Receipt
```

See the [ArrayList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) documentation for the methods you can use

Answer (score 2):

The correct way to do this in Java is to create an interface that represents the common attributes of objects you wish to store in the collection and then have each class of those objects implement that interface.

```
interface BakeryItem {
    String getName();
    float getPrice();
}

class WeightedItem {
    private final float weight;
    private final float pricePerPound;

    public float getPrice() {
        return weight * pricePerPound;
    }
}

List<BakeryItem> bakeryItems;
```

If you need to use specific attributes of the different classes then I recommend using the [visitor pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern) to separate the logic from the data.

Storing different classes in a collection is possible using `List<Object>` and casting on retrieval but this is not a recommended approach for a variety of reasons.